# No consigo que el gamOBbject siga la trayectoria indicada

Tags: c#, unity

**Necesito que la bola siga la trayectoria del click, pero aunque normalice el vector y se lo asigne al rigibody, no consigo que continue la trayectoria.  ¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?
Inicio la simulación, le doy click algún lugar de la pantalla y el objeto comienza a dirigirse a ese punto, se queda parado en ese punto (una vez llega) y no consigo que continúe con la trayectoria. Una vez se ha parado comienza a "temblar el objeto" (el objeto se mueve muy pocas unidades sin yo indicárselo y no logro arreglarlo.**

```
void Start()
{
    posicionIncial = transform.position;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.anyKey)
    {
        if (juegoIniciado == false)
        {
            posicionIncial = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,
                Input.mousePosition.y, -Camera.main.transform.position.z));
            JuegoIniciado();
        }
    }


    direccionInicial = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, posicionIncial, velocidadBola * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.position = direccionInicial;

    _rigidbody2D.velocity = CalcularDireccionBola() * (velocidadBola);
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    analizadorVelocidad = _rigidbody2D.velocity;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision2D)    
{
    if(!collision2D.transform.CompareTag("LimiteInferior"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Estas dentro del OnCollision");
        direccion=Vector2.Reflect(analizadorVelocidad,collision2D.GetContact(0).normal);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.zero;
    }
    if (Math.Abs(direccion.y) < velocidadMinima)
    {
        direccion.y = velocidadMinima * Math.Sign(direccion.y);
    }

    _rigidbody2D.velocity = direccion;

}

private bool JuegoIniciado()
{
    return juegoIniciado = true;
}

Vector3 CalcularDireccionBola()
{
    return Vector3.Normalize(posicionClick - transform.position);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

El problemas esta en la funcion  CalcularDireccionBola () por que lo estas ejecutando cada frame.

```
Vector3 CalcularDireccionBola()
{
    return Vector3.Normalize(posicionClick - transform.position);
}
```

Mejor simplemente guardar una variable vector2 direccion calculado al presionar cualquier tecla

```
public class Bolita : Monobehaviour
{
    public float velocidad = 3;
    public Vector2 direccionIr = Vector2.zero;

    // solo se debe ejecutar una vez :)
    public void PresionarClick()
    {
        Vector2 posicionClick= Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,
            Input.mousePosition.y, -Camera.main.transform.position.z));

        direccionIr = (posicionClick - (Vector2)transform.position).normalized;
    }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(direccionIr != Vector2.zero)
        {   
            transform.position += (Vector2)direccionIr * velocidad * Time.deltatime * 100;
        }
    }
    
    public Keycode tecla = Keycode.Space;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(tecla)) PresionarClick()
    }
}
```